# Intellij 13 ultimate runs geb tests smoothly but they wait when run independently

Tags: testing, selenium, groovy, cucumber, geb

I am using cucumber groovy with geb.
Here is my profile and driver

```
FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
firefoxProfile.setAcceptUntrustedCertificates(true);
firefoxProfile.setAssumeUntrustedCertificateIssuer(false);
firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk",
        "text/csv,application/pdf,application/csv,application/vnd.ms-excel");
firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showAlertOnComplete",false);
firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", false);
firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.useWindow", false);
firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.deleteTempFileOnExit", true);
firefoxProfile.setPreference("webdriver.load.strategy", "unstable")

driver = {
    def driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxProfile)
    driver
}
```

Here is my step definition (FYI, this is the firstmost step)

```
MyPage.setUrl(Globals.get(key))
to MyPage
waitFor(10,0) {
    ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.tagName("title"))
}
at MyPage
```

I noticed that if i put a breakpoint at "at MyPage" in intellij and debug then it breaks at that point and then i can resume. However if I simply run either from Intellij or using `./gradlew clean cucumber`
then the page loads and waits for a long time. I don't think it ever proceeds (only waited for a minute to check)

Whats the issue here ?

---

**Update 1**

```
class MyPage extends Page{

    static url = ""

    static at = {
        module1.attrib.value() != null
        Globals.get(module1.attrib.value())
    }

    static content = {
        module1 { module Module1 } // Simple Geb Module
        module2 { fieldsMap ->  module Module2, fieldsMap: fieldsMap }
    }
}


class Module2 extends Module {

    def fieldsMap
    static content = {
        textField { $("input", name: fieldsMap['textFieldName']) }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you post the code from MyPage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated version of Selenium and firefox fixed the issue.
Closing this

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it in a more gebish way:

1. Set the url explicitly in a subClass of MyPage - you should really try to use one page object per page.
2. define an at condition and use it to test for the waitFor condition for the page to wait till its loaded.

**By default an at condition will wait for its condition to be true**.

and

do not use ExpectedConditions try something more Gebish like:

```
waitFor { title != "" }
```

In your at condition you have not properly specified a truth statement. Although I am not sure what Globals.get(module1.attrib.value()) returns? But it looks like you should remove this line and do this logic somewhere else.

Calling value returns a string.

Module 1

```
class MyPage extends Page{

    static url = ""

    static at = { 
        waitFor { module1.attrib.value() != ""  }
    }   
}

MyPage.setUrl(Globals.get(key))
to MyPage
at MyPage
```

Just nit picking here:

```
driver = {
    new FirefoxDriver(firefoxProfile)
}
```

Comment: I dont want to set the url that way as I am reusing MyPage for lots of pages

Comment: Also I think this is perfectly fine condition. The reason i am doing this is because firefox profile has a preference `webdriver.load.strategy` which is set to unstable. This causes selenium not to wait for the page to fully load. Then the following waitFor becomes important as its a good condition to check for page to be loaded.


 waitFor(10,0) {
     ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.tagName("title"))
 }

Comment: Another observation i made is since the breakpoint is at the line 'at MyPage', me debugging with intellij isn't giving any more time  for selenium to load than me running directly using gradle command mentioned above

Comment: You can get the same result in a simpler way using Geb without using Selenium directly. That's the point of it. waitFor {$('body').displayed}

Comment: ok even with that, the page loads and still waits for a long time